# select all elements of the form but need exclude some elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to pass form variables so I do

```
$("#form1").serializeArray();
```

but I do not need to select some elements so I need something like that

```
$("#form1 not .someclass").serializeArray();
```

How to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:not()`

```
$('#form1 :not(".someclass")');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#form").not(".someClass").serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To select all all input,select,textarea fields excluding .someclass elements

```
$("#form1 :input:not(.someclass)").serializeArray();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TpL6a/)